# Make Wine run its applications as user profile, not Administrator

Tags: linux, postgresql, wine

For a very specific case, I need to install PostgreSQL under Wine to run a Windows application that packs it's own installation of PostgreSQL even if PostgreSQL is already installed, for security reasons.

The installation goes smoothly until it needs to install PostgreSQL. During its installation, PostgreSQL throws an error saying that it does not allow to be installed as Administrator (again, for security reasons).

So my only problem is that Wine reports to the applications it runs as if they were being run by Administrator.

**Two possible solutions are:**

1. Make Wine report it's running its applications by another user than Administrator, but still with admin privileges,
   or;
2. Force PostgreSQL to be installed and run by Administrator, but as I'm not sure if I really can change any option or argument in this PostgreSQL installation specifically, the solution above is the best choice.

I can't figure out a way to make it. Is it possible?

**I would go as far as patching Wine's source code, if necessary.**

Comment: Under Windows an installation always runs as TrustedInstaller which has admin privileges. Do you mean to say that you have found a way of installing PostgreSQL under Windows not as admin?

Comment: I guess the case is different. Under Windows, it installs as a privileged user, yes. In fact it needs those privileges to make changes in folders other than the user's home folder. But I think PostgreSQL checks whether it is being run by the _user_ Administrator itself or not. And that's the problem under Wine, it reports _being_ user Administrator, not only a privileged user, probably as an easy way to bypass TrustedInstaller's needs for admin privileges, as you mentioned.

Comment: is the app able connect to postgresql using tcp protocol?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I tried installing PostgreSQL on Linux and try to connect to it from Wine using ODBC, with no luck. But I might have configured it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to perform the installation on windows then copy the postgresql database, files and registry to wine.

http://wine-wiki.org/index.php/Advanced_Wine_User_Information#Copying_Software_across_from_a_native_Windows_Installation

Comment: or try to change wine windows version with winecfg to win98 and see if it still  sees the user name as Administrator